Unit testing class with flow collection in init
How can I best go about unit testing flows that are collected in a class's init function?
The only solution I've come up with so far requires hard-coded delays.
Consider a sample implementation of a NotificationService and a UserSession that uses said service.
class NotificationService {

    private val notificationFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Notification>()

    suspend fun notify(notification: Notification) { notificationFlow.emit(notification) }

    fun subscribe() = notificationFlow.asSharedFlow()
}

class UserSession(
    coroutineContext: CoroutineContext,
    private val notificationService: NotificationService
) {

    /* ... user related fields ... */

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    init {
        scope.launch {
            notificationService.subscribe().collect { /* Handle notifications */ }
        }
    }
    /* ... user related functions ... */
}


When attempting to write a basic unit test, similar to:
@Test
fun `Can instantiate class`() = runTest {
    val notificationService = spy(NotificationService())
    val unit = unit(testScheduler, notificationService)
    verify(notificationService).subscribe()
}

Then the test will become flaky, as occationally, the init-function will not have time to start collecting before the unit test verifies that the function NotificationService#subscribe() has been called.
How can I best wait until unit has completed it's instantiation?
